# CROSS JOIN columns of a table with its data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

## Problem description with an example

Assuming I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyData(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NotUniqueCol INT,
    ColA NVARCHAR(128),
    ColB NVARCHAR(128)
)
INSERT INTO MyData (Id, NotUniqueCol, ColA, ColB)
VALUES (1, 1, 'a', 'A')
     , (2, 1, 'b', 'B')
     , (3, 2, 'c', 'C')
```

And a stored procedure which takes a *table name*, a *column name* and a *column value*:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
(
    @tableName NVARCHAR(128),
    @columnName NVARCHAR(128),
    @id INT,
)
```

And I execute it

```
EXEC GetData 'MyData', 'NotUniqueCol', 1
```

It should return something like this:

```
 RowNumber  │  ColumnName    │ ColumnValue
────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────
 1          │ 'Id'           │ 1
 1          │ 'NotUniqueCol' │ 1
 1          │ 'ColA'         │ 'a'
 1          │ 'ColB'         │ 'A'
 2          │ 'Id'           │ 2
 2          │ 'NotUniqueCol' │ 1
 2          │ 'ColA'         │ 'b'
 2          │ 'ColB'         │ 'B'
```

## Outline Solution

The problem is the body of `GetData` because everything must be generic.

My idea are these steps:

1. Get all table names and join them to the columns and filter the result.
2. Execute a dynamic query which selects the matching data from the table and numerate the rows.
3. Do a `CROSS JOIN` with the results of 2. und 3.

## Snippets

**Step 1**

```
SELECT c.[name]
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE t.[name] = @tableName
```

**Step 2**

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    = ' SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY myTable.' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' DESC) AS [RowNumber], myTable.*'
    + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' AS myTable'
    + ' WHERE myTable.' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' = ' + CAST(@id AS NVARCHAR(16))
PRINT @query
EXEC sp_sqlexec @query
```

## Get the result using a cursor

This code works, but I do not like it because of the cursor.

```
-- The parameters from the SP
DECLARE  @tableName NVARCHAR(128)='MyData',
         @columnName NVARCHAR(128)='NotUniqueCol',
         @id INT=1

--The body of the SP
CREATE TABLE #result (RowNumber INT, ColumnName NVARCHAR(128), ColumnValue SQL_VARIANT)

DECLARE @column NVARCHAR(128);
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR
FOR 
    SELECT c.[name]
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
    WHERE t.[name] = @tableName
OPEN myCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor 
INTO @column

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) 
        = ' SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY myTable.' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' DESC) AS [RowNumber], ''' + @column + ''' AS [ColumnName], myTable.' + QUOTENAME(@column)
        + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' AS myTable'
        + ' WHERE myTable.' + QUOTENAME(@columnName) + ' = ' + CAST(@id AS NVARCHAR(16))
    PRINT @query

    INSERT INTO #result(RowNumber, ColumnName, ColumnValue)
    EXEC sp_sqlexec @query

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor 
    INTO @column
END
CLOSE myCursor;  
DEALLOCATE myCursor;  

SELECT * FROM #result
ORDER BY RowNumber, ColumnName

DROP TABLE #result
```

## Final Question

I have not a good idea for **Step 3** which do not use a cursor. It works well, but is there a solution using a `CROSS JOIN` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Table-Valued-Function which will convert virtually any Table, Query, or Row into an EAV Structure.

The First column in the query (or table) will be the ENTITY and please note that it will be excluded from the the values (optional)

Certainly, UNPIVOT is more performant, but this does not require Dynamic SQL, and there are no datatype conflicts, and the performance is very respectable.

I should add that NULL values WILL be excluded.  I'm at a loss on how to include them.

**Example 1**

```
Select * From [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select * From MyData for XML RAW))
```

**Returns**

```
Entity  Attribute       Value
1       NotUniqueCol    1      --<< Notice ID is NOT a row
1       ColA            a
1       ColB            A
2       NotUniqueCol    1
2       ColA            b
2       ColB            B
3       NotUniqueCol    2
3       ColA            c
3       ColB            C
```

**Example 2 -- With Row_Number() as the ENTITY**

```
Select * From [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select RowNumber=Row_Number() over (Order By ID),* From MyData for XML RAW))
```

**Returns**

```
Entity  Attribute       Value
1       Id              1      --<< Notice ID IS a row ... 1st column is Row_Number()
1       NotUniqueCol    1
1       ColA            a
1       ColB            A
2       Id              2
2       NotUniqueCol    1
2       ColA            b
2       ColB            B
3       Id              3
3       NotUniqueCol    2
3       ColA            c
3       ColB            C
```

**Example 3 with CROSS APPLY - Especially for Larger Tables**

```
Select B.*
 From  MyData A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select A.* for XML RAW)) B
```

**Returns**

```
Entity  Attribute       Value
1       NotUniqueCol    1
1       ColA            a
1       ColB            A
2       NotUniqueCol    1
2       ColA            b
2       ColB            B
3       NotUniqueCol    2
3       ColA            c
3       ColB            C
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-EAV](@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    with cteKey(k) as (Select Top 1 xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') From @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow) Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt))    

    Select Entity    = xRow.value('@*[1]','varchar(50)')
          ,Attribute = xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
          ,Value     = xAtt.value('.','varchar(max)') 
    From  @XML.nodes('/row') As A(xRow)
    Cross Apply A.xRow.nodes('./@*') As B(xAtt)
    Where xAtt.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Not In (Select k From cteKey)
)
-- Notes:  First Field in Query will be the Entity
-- Select * From [dbo].[udf-EAV]((Select UTCDate=GetUTCDate(),* From sys.dm_os_sys_info for XML RAW))
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you!

Comment: @Koopakiller Happy it helped